# Applying a filter to a buddypress function

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I'd like to modify the output of this function using a separate bit of code that can live inside the functions.php in the theme folder. Thanks!

```
function bp_group_status_message( $group = null ) {
global $groups_template;

if ( ! $group )
    $group =& $groups_template->group;

if ( 'private' == $group->status ) {
    if ( ! bp_group_has_requested_membership() ) {
        if ( is_user_logged_in() )
            $message = __( 'This is a private group and you must request group membership in order to join.', 'buddypress' );
        else
            $message = __( 'This is a private group. To join you must be a registered site member and request group membership.', 'buddypress' );

    } else {
        $message = __( 'This is a private group. Your membership request is awaiting approval from the group administrator.', 'buddypress' );
    }

} else {
    $message = __( 'This is a hidden group and only invited members can join.', 'buddypress' );
}

echo apply_filters( 'bp_group_status_message', $message, $group );
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic structure:

```
function new_group_status_message( $message, $group ) {
  $message = 'new message'; 
  return $message; 
}
add_filter('bp_group_status_message', 'new_group_status_message', 1, 2 );
```